# How do I get Latency from Discord.Net?

Tags: vb.net, discord, discord.net

**How do I get Latency from Discord.Net?**

I haven't found an answer for two hours. help me!

Comment: Which latency might you be talking about? Time for your program to receive a message received event? Time for your program to respond to a message received event? Time your program's message took to send? Well in any case, just compare a message's timestamp to the current time.

Answer (score 0):

The DiscordSocketClient has a property called latency. This is the latency to Discord's servers. If you have a sharded bot you would need to get latency per shard.

Hope that helps!